# web3.eth.personal.newAccount + JSON RPC error connected to ropsten in metamask

Tags: web3js, accounts

**Updated:**

I have a function where I init web3 and included `web3.eth.personal.newAccount` at the bottom of the function to create a new account.

```
initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      App.web3Provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }

    web3.eth.personal.newAccount('abc123').then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }); 
  },
```

When connected to localhost:8545(ganache) in metamask and test this, it generates a new account, but when connected to ropsten, I get the following error:

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."}

Why can't I generate a new account if I'm connected to Ropsten? I use web3 1.0 btw.

Comment: Have you tested any other `web3` calls as a sanity check? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: yes I've tried with `web3.eth.getAccounts()` and it's working fine. I've changed my network connection in metamask to ropsten test network, and now I'm getting this error in the console. `inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."}`

Comment: it just worked with localhost:8545 ganache! why can't it generate new account connected to ropsten?

Comment: So your question is why is MetaMask failing? Are you hosting your web page on a server or just opening the file on your local desktop?

Comment: On a local desktop

Comment: User verified that the same error occurs even when using lite-server to host his page.

Comment: does that mean I need to try with a different server?